# Troolean-type values

Tags: c#, .net

I have a speech class in my app and would like to be able to see if it's listening, recording, dictating, or non-responsive;

What I would like is to be able to do is assign some kind of variable (SpeechState) just 1 of 3 possible values, and check against it too, like this:

```
startListeningButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SpeechState = SpeechState.Listening;
}

stopListeningButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(SpeechState.Listening)
   {
      // Code to STOP listening goes here.
   }
}
```

I have tried implementing troolean, but that's not exactly what I was after. I am after *something* similar to this:

```
if(checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
{
   // Do something
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Make a `SpeechState` [enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Troolean: A slang term to describe Microsoft's true/false/error scheme used in many places in the Win32 API. It's used to describe when something has 3 states, as compared to Boolean, which has two states (usually true or false).

Comment: another alternitive is to use a nullable boolean. This allows for 3 states, and helps if you are storing it in the database.

Comment: Troolean is a horrible horrible word.

Comment: @Hogan: It *Trooly* is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should make an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) for this.

```
public enum SpeechState
{
   Listening,
   Recording,
   Dictating,
   Unresponsive
}
```

You can then use this exactly as you've shown for setting, though the check would be:

```
if(this.SpeechState == SpeechState.Listening)
```

---

Edit in response to comments:

In order to place this on your class, you need a property to store it:

```
public class YourClass
{
     public SpeechState SpeechState { get; set; }
}
```

You can then set this property on the class to a value.

Comment: I didn't think it was working when i tried this, No matter how I tried to assign to it it wouldn't work. How would I assign to this?

Comment: @Jase You need a field or property for this on your class:  `public SpeechState SpeechState { get; set; }`

Comment: Probably should call the `SpeechState` enum something else, like `if (this.mySpeechState == SpeechState.Listening)`?  Calling the instantiation the same name as the type won't work?

Comment: @John Any reason why?  Using the name makes it very clear what the property refers to - there's a reason that name was picked in the first place :)  (See `CheckBox.CheckState` for a good example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstate.aspx )

Comment: I guess I'm thinking C++ not C#. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use an enumeration:

```
 public enum SpeechState
 {
     Listening,
     Recording,
     Dictating,
     Unresponsive
 }
```

Comment: I didn't think it was working when i tried this, No matter how I tried to assign to it it wouldn't work. How would I assign to this?

Comment: You say `SpeechState state = SpeechState.Recording ;` Enums are syntactic sugar on top of integer data types. Each value is sugar for an integer value. In the above example `Listening` is 0, `Recording` 1, `Dictating` 2, and `Unresponsive` 3. You can can also say things like `SpeechState state = (SpeechState) 123456789;`, which is perfectly legal. There is no requirement that the value assigned to an enum be actually *valid* for that particular enum.

Comment: @NicholasCarey, that's a pretty *sweet* answer.